# The development server returned response error code: 500.Error: Unable to resolve module ./index

Tags: android-studio, react-native, command-line-interface

I've created a new react-native project using command prompt and react-native command. When I tried to open the project using an Android Studio emulator I got the following error:

```html
The development server returned response error code: 500

URL: http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false

Body:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Error: Unable to resolve module ./index from
 D:\ReactNative\myreactdemo\node_modules\react-native\scripts/.: The module ./index could not be found from
D:\ReactNative\myreactdemo\node_modules\react-native\scripts/.. Indeed, none of these files exist:<br> &nbsp;* D:\ReactNative\myreactdemo\node_modules\react-native\scripts\index(.native||.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)`<br> &nbsp;*D:\ReactNative\myreactdemo\node_modules\react-native\scripts\index\index(.native||.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)`<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (D:\ReactNative\myreactdemo\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:163:15)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (D:\ReactNative\myreactdemo\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ResolutionRequest.js:52:18)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (D:\ReactNative\myreactdemo\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:283:16)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at D:\ReactNative\myreactdemo\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:261:42<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Server.&lt;anonymous&gt; (D:\ReactNative\myreactdemo\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:1038:41)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Generator.next (&lt;anonymous&gt;)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at asyncGeneratorStep (D:\ReactNative\myreactdemo\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:99:24)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at _next (D:\ReactNative\myreactdemo\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:119:9)</pre>
</body>
</html>

processBundleResult
    BundleDownloader.java:296
access$200
    BundleDownloader.java:37
onResponse
    BundleDownloader.java:174
execute
    RealCall.java:206
run
    NamedRunnable.java:32
runWorker
    ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167
run
    ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641
run
    Thread.java:764
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit

> \node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\runAndroid\runAndroid.js and replaced
>   cwd: scriptsDir with cwd: process.cwd()

Answer (score 0):

`react-native start --reset-cache` in one terminal and left it open

`react-native run-android` in another terminal

Answer (score 0):

This error is by nodeJS server. And the reason for it is because of syntax error. Can you please share the code (./index File) where error is occurring.